# Display remote image

Tags: c#, image

I have a directory on my web server which contains images and I am trying to workout how I can display them on a windows form.

I am running a query to get the images name for the required record so that part is done. How do I then display that image. This is the code so far:

```
string FltLogoVal = myReader.GetString("Logo");
FltLogo.Text = FltLogoVal;

PictureBox imageControl = new PictureBox();
imageControl.Width = 150;
imageControl.Height = 50;

Bitmap image = new Bitmap("http://www.maydomain.com/airline_logos/").FltLogo.Text;
imageControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
imageControl.Image = (Image)image;

Controls.Add(imageControl);
```

I am getting an error where the line is:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap("http://www.mydomain.com/airline_logos/").FltLogo.Text;
```

The error is:
'System.Drawing.Bitmap' does not contain a definition for 'FltLogo' and no extension method 'FltLogo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have two questions:

1. am I going about this in the correct way?
2. if so can anyone see where I am going wrong.

As you can see I am very new to C# so please be kind with any replies.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's an `FltLogo`? I think you mean that to be part of your URL.

Comment: try Bitmap image = new Bitmap("http://www.maydomain.com/airline_logos/" + FltLogo.Text);

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the image name to the URL:

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap("http://www.maydomain.com/airline_logos/" + FltLogo.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you're trying to call the FltLogo.Text method on the Bitmap constructor.  If I'm getting the right idea from your code, what you mean to do is more like

`Bitmap image = new Bitmap("http://www.maydomain.com/airline_logos/" + FltLogoVal)`